# CSS inset box shadow on table cell is mis-aligned

Tags: html, css

So there's probably a simple answer to this, but I can't seem to get my CSS inset box shadow to work correctly on a table cell. I have the following CSS rules:

```
table { 
    border: 1px solid #aaa; 
}
table th, td { 
    width: 76px; 
    height: 50px; 
    vertical-align: middle; 
    text-align: center;
}
tr { 
    border: 1px solid #aaa; 
}
td.color {
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 10px 0 #222;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 10px 0 #222;
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 10px 0 #222;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
td.red { ... }
td.green { ... }
```

So I'm trying to add classes `.color` and  `.red`, `.green`, etc. to certain cells with the inset shadow to have them look indented in the table row. For some reason, the inset shadow is mis-aligned by 1px.

I posted an image of the problem here:

[image]

Resulting in the bottom and right edges having 1px of background showing through.

Any ideas? Thanks!

-Nate

Comment: The image looks good, are you sure that is the correct one?

Comment: It would be helpful to state which browsers show the problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Works if you add `display: block;` to `td.color`

```
td.color {
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 10px 0 #222;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 10px 0 #222;
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 10px 0 #222;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    display: block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/DjAfw/

*tested on Chrome*

Comment: This works, thanks! The only catch is that since it's `display: block`, the cell is no longer vertical aligned middle. I can fix it with manually setting line-height, but that feels hacky...any thoughts?

Comment: @nathan Ah now I see in Chrome the issue. I was using FireFox. I would point out, that even though this solution works you are still using the incorrect syntax. Please see my answer below for the correct syntax for an inset box shadow.

Answer (score 5):

This is ie9 input box-shadow bug solution in table

```
input { box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #3699FF; border-collapse: separate; }
```

**border-collapse: separate;** is kick point

Comment: border-collapse: separate! this is it! Thanks, although I think we need to add position:relative at least for ie8.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid I cannot replicate your issue, however you have syntax issues with your inset box shadow. Please try this code instead:

```
td.color {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #222 inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #222 inset;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #222 inset;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only noticing this 1px issue in Chrome (tested in Safari 5 & FF 5 also)

http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/sZqV5/

the `border` on the cells appear to be related to the issue, you can remove the cell border and the shadow is correct.  Also like @Jason Gennaro already posted, `display:block` on the cell also fixes the shadow.

Consider posting your findings on the Chromium Bug List:  http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list

Comment: Thanks, I'll go ahead and post to the bug list.